# AngularJS filtering ng-repeat on an array

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular. The below code dynamically shows/hides rows of a table based on a `<select multiple>` control.

The code works but I wonder if there is a way to convert the expression in `data-ng-if` to a filter expression without creating a custom filter. Also not sure which is a better approach performancewise.

```
<select id="psgs" data-ng-model="ctrl.showSubGroups"
   ng-options="item.id as item.name group by item.productGroup.name for item in ctrl.productSubGroupList"
   multiple>
</select>

<tr 
   data-ng-if="ctrl.showSubGroups.indexOf(product.productSubGroup.id) > -1" 
   data-ng-repeat="product in ctrl.productList | filter: ??? | orderBy: ctrl.seq">
   ...
</tr>
```

Comment: what kind of filtration you want?, any use case

Comment: Exactly the same as in `ng-if`, but as a filter expression.

Comment: again, there can be many scenarios.. like `ng-if="$even"`, can filter out odd result.It all depends on your use case. If you have a particular requirement, state it in question.

Comment: @Arthur why do you not want to use a custom filter?

Comment: @tanmay Because I'm also not sure how to access the array of selected subgroups stored as a controller property from a filter.

Comment: @Arthur you don't need to create filter using `angular.filter(...`.. it's in your controller itself.. fairly simple to use. I have added the same as answer. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using custom filter and it's better approach as compared to having `ng-if` on each iteration. You shouldn't be repeating the loop for those which are not going to be rendered.

Here's how. In your HTML, use `customFilter` (which is a custom filter function we created) like this:

```
<tr 
   data-ng-repeat="product in ctrl.productList | filter: ctrl.customFilter | orderBy: ctrl.seq">
   ...
</tr>
```

Now, in your controller, you can have `customFilter` function like this:

```
ctrl.customFilter = function(product) {
  return ctrl.showSubGroups.indexOf(product.productSubGroup.id) > -1
}
```

Here's a simple [**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6RYlbsHvy1fdhKW9cQRj?p=preview) with sample data

Comment: Thanks, it is easier than what I thought from the documentation. :)

Comment: @Arthur in Angular most of the things are easier than shown in docs :D glad I could help